# How to write programmatically some unicode text in RTF format?

Tags: c++, unicode, rtf

In order to generate RTF programmatically I have decided to use rtflib v1.0 from codeproject.com. But I can't understand how to generate text in russian unicode. So I need to generate a unicode text. Could someone help me?

P.S. Honeslty, I could write in .rtf file some text in, only by opening it with MS Word. But after writing some text in unicode, WordPad showed text is correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps:

1. Create a file named .rtf
2. Open  .rtf
3. Write there the following code in order to generate an RTF file which contains UTF-8 encoded content:

   ```
   {\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi

   {\fonttbl
   {\f26\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2{\*\panose 010a0502050306030303}Sylfaen;}
   }

   {\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \f26 \u<unicode number>\'3f\u<unicode number>\'3f\u<unicode number>\'3  A lot of other text and symbols 

   like this: + - *  _ }


   }
   ```

For example:

```
{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi

{\fonttbl
{\f26\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2{\*\panose 010a0502050306030303}Sylfaen;}
}

{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \f26 \u1329\'3f\u1330\'3f\u1331\'3f\u1332\'3f - these are first 4 latters of Armenian alphabet}

}
```

Foe more details see the UTF-8 encoding table [here](http://doc.infosnel.nl/extreme_utf-8.html). And RTF spec is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dd422b8d-ff06-4207-b476-6b5396a18a2b&displaylang=en).